# Inline ifelse assignment in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let the following data set be given:

```
library('data.table')

set.seed(1234)
DT       <- data.table(x = LETTERS[1:10], y =sample(10))
my.rows  <- sample(1:dim(DT)[1], 3)
```

I want to add a new column to the data set such that, whenever the rows of the data set match the row numbers given by `my.rows` the entry is populated with, say, true, or false otherwise.

I have got `DT[my.rows, z:= "true"]`, which gives

```
head(DT)
   x y    z
1: A 2   NA
2: B 6   NA
3: C 5 true 
4: D 8   NA
5: E 9 true 
6: F 4   NA
```

but I do not know how to automatically populate the `else` condition as well, at the same time. I guess I should make use of some sort of inline `ifelse` but I am lacking the correct syntax.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the data you provided.

Comment: Set any seed you like, the actual output is irrelevant. I have edited it anyway to make it clearer.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco  Please check the solution below.

Comment: What's wrong with your own solution? You can leave the rest as `NA`s and if you want to filter by them you could just do `DT[is.na(z)]` and get over with. I would also suggest you will assign a boolean there, namely  `DT[my.rows, z:= TRUE]` so you could then filter by `DT[(z)]` for example.

Comment: In the example at hand this is true, although in the case I am dealing with I need to actually populate the entries with information (rather than boolean variables). That is why I was looking for some sort of inline `ifelse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare the 'my.rows' with the sequence of row using `%in%` to create a logical vector and assign (`:=`) it to create 'z' column.

```
 DT[, z:= 1:.N %in% my.rows ]
```

Or another option would be to create 'z' as a column of 'FALSE', using 'my.rows' as 'i', we assign the elements in 'z' that correspond to 'i' as 'TRUE'.

```
 DT[, z:= FALSE][my.rows, z:= TRUE]
```

Comment: The latter works very fine, since it allows to choose what you want to populate the entries with. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
DT <- cbind(DT,z = ifelse(DT[, .I] %in% my.rows , T, NA))

> DT
#    x  y    z
# 1: A  2   NA
# 2: B  6   NA
# 3: C  5 TRUE
# 4: D  8   NA
# 5: E  9 TRUE
# 6: F  4   NA
# 7: G  1 TRUE
# 8: H  7   NA
# 9: I 10   NA
#10: J  3   NA
```

Comment: This very inefficient solution for a `data.table` question.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid the double assignment, if possible.